# Complex Relationship in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using ActiveRecord with Ruby on Rails and I need to model a rather complex relationship which I don't think falls well into a normal has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.  To preface, this is a application for managing soccer referee game assignments (trivial implementation for a class, not a real production app).

I have a Game model which has a referee, ar1 and ar2 which are id numbers which correspond directly to a User model's id (the built in id created by activerecord).  So my question is, I want to be able to show a user's games on the show.html.erb page using activerecord, but I'm not really sure how to establish the relationship in activerecord and still maintain the sense of game assignment position (referee, ar1, ar2).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is adding a `type` in your model.

after adding type you can call like below

```
@g = Game.first

@gamers = g.users.all(:where => ["type = 'Gamer'"]
@referee = g.users.all(:where => ["type = 'Referee'"]
```

Comment: I'm confused, I cant do STI because a user could be a referee for one game, but AR1 for another.